# How to change the column name of the edit icon in an interactive report?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an interactive report in which the link column to edit the data doesn't have a column name and I don't seem to find where to write one.
[image: interactive report]

I tried to find a setting where I could rename the column but didn't find any solution.
[image: Settings in the page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to add one virtual column like:

```
select
  ... 
  null as link -- set this column as link and you will be 
               -- able to change the column header
from your_table;
```

Comment: It was my secondary option, I tried to avoid it but finally did it since it's the only one that I can do. Thanks for the help